# Project reactor, Convert Flux into Map<String,List<Data>>

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, reactive, webflux

I have a `list` of `Data` object

```
public class Data{
    private String id;
    private String sharedId;
}
```

How to convert this `list` into `Map<String,List<Data>>`, collecting the `data object` sharing the same `sharedId` together

I have tried to use this line of code, but no luck

```
Map<String,List<Data>> dataMap= Flux.fromIterable(list)
        .collectMap(item-> item.getSharedId(),
                item-> item);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream API is not equal to Reactive API and they are *not interchangeable*.

---

Use **Stream API** for grouping into `Map<String, List<Data>>` from `List<Data>`:

```
Map<String,List<Data>> dataMap = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getSharedId));
```

Using **Reactive API** to achieve you achieve `Flux<GroupedFlux<String, Data>>` analogically or expand the structure using `Map.Entry`:

```
Flux<GroupedFlux<String, Data>> groupedFlux = Flux.fromIterable(list)
    .groupBy(Data::getSharedId);
```

```
Flux<Map.Entry<String, List<Data>>> groupedFlux = Flux.fromIterable(list)
    .groupBy(Data::getSharedId)
    .flatMap(group -> group
        .collectList()
        .map(listOfData -> Map.entry(group.key(), listOfData)));
```

Answer (score 3):

With regards to previous answers from Nikolas & Joao you could also use:

```
Mono<Map<String, Collection<Data>>> mapCollection = Flux.fromIterable(list)                                       
                                              .collectMultimap(Data::getSharedId, item -> item);
```

you can map further to specific collection if it needs to be a list:

```
Mono<Map<String, List<Data>>> mapList = mapCollection
    .map(map -> map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> List.copyOf(e.getValue()))))
```

or use:

```
Mono<Map<String, List<Data>>> mapList2 = Mono.just(list)
                                         .map(l -> l.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getSharedId)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```java
Map<String,List<Data>> dataMap = 
    list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Data::getSharedId));
```